# glmer and number of groups

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm running a mixed effects logistic regression model with glmer in R. I have data on 1197 participants in 17 facilities, and I'm looking at survival status (dead or alive) as the outcome event. In my final model, there's only one random effect which is facility, so I should end up with 17 groups, but my output says 14 groups... is it because in 3 of the 17 facilities, there was an insufficient number of participants or events (death), so these groups were dropped?

Facility A: 4 deaths among 8 participants
Facility B: 2 deaths among 6 participants
Facility C: 0 death among 1 participant

`glmer(status ~ I(age/10) + sex + smaf + goc + covidCat + chf + ncd + thrombo + lpnCat + I(beds/100) + rz + ach + audit + staffinfCat + (1 | ltcf), family = binomial(link="logit"), data = pubC, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))`